# Python repeate my code so many times i want

Tags: python, repeat

I try to repeat this code 5 times, but I don't know how I can do this. Can you help me?
This is my code:

```
import pyautogui, time
time.sleep(5)
f = open("Disco", 'r')
for word in f:
    pyautogui.typewrite(word)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
```

How can I repeat this so many times I want?

Comment: for i in range(int:times)

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work

Comment: for i in range(5): It looks like it worked for you lol. The int:times is a hint for a number to go there (int) not (float)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you used the for loop in your code, use a slightly different form to repeat the code 5 times:

```
import pyautogui, time

for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(5)
    f = open("Disco", 'r')
    for word in f:
        pyautogui.typewrite(word)
        pyautogui.press("enter")
```

You don't want to import the packages multiple times, so I excluded them from the loop.